# Lotus NotesStream how to read character by character

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

How do read from a NotesStream character by character. i.e one character at a time in a loop. NoteasStream.Read(1) reads one character but returns a variant array which I am not able to convert to the specific character.

Comment: Be careful using Read method, which doesn't read one character -- it reads one byte. If you assume that's the same thing, you're writing code that'll fail with some character sets or just some characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you can read byte by byte from stream

```vb
Dim stream As NotesStream
Dim bytes As variant
...
Do
    bytes = stream.Read(1)
    Print bytes(0)
Loop Until stream.IsEOS
```

Probably more efficient is it to read more then just one byte at a time from stream

```vb
Dim stream As NotesStream
Dim bytes As variant
...
Do
    bytes = stream.Read(32767)
    ForAll b In bytes
        Print b
    End ForAll
Loop Until stream.IsEOS
```

If you want to get characters instead of bytes one by one then you can use this

```vb
Dim stream As NotesStream
...
Dim buffer As String
Dim i As Long
Dim char As String
buffer = stream.ReadText()
For i=1 To Len(buffer)
    char = Mid(buffer, i, 1)
    Print char
Next
```

Comment: The problem with Mid() or Mid$() is that it quickly becomes very slow and inefficient as the String length gets longer...